# Howto embed font variants in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I need to embed local .ttf files on a JavaFX project with some variants (bold, italic and so on) but the css parser seems to not support font properties in **@font-face** declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf');
    font-style: italic;
}
```

> WARNING: CSS Error parsing
>   jar:file:/home/test/dist/run736633436/test.jar!/it/test/vending/css/application.css:
>   Unexpected TOKEN [:] at [8,15] mag 06, 2015 3:40:15 PM
>   com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser fontFace WARNING: CSS Error
>   parsing
>   jar:file:/home/test/dist/run736633436/test.jar!/it/test/vending/css/application.css:
>   Unexpected TOKEN [:] at [13,14]

How could I achieve this?

==EDIT==

---

Notice that the parser complains on **font-weight: bold;** and **font-style: italic;** rules.

Comment: The `font-family` should have the name of the font-family that you want to use in all the css file. The font-family to be used by you should have unique names like `OpenSansRegular`, `OpenSansBold`, `OpenSansBoldItalic`. Though I am not sure if this is exactly the issue as your CSS Error doesn't say much, but it is worth giving a try.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Nope, defining different families won't matter: the parser still complains on **font-weight: bold;** and **font-style: italic;**. Use of multiple same-font-family with different font propertis is actually correct; see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_font-face_rule_bold) - at least speaking about css3.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a solution. Try to swap the `font-weight` and `font-style` attributes with the `src` attribute. In your case your css would look like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url('fonts/OpenSans-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf');
}
```

I had the same issue and swapping the attributes did the job. I have no idea why that is but it seems to resolve the issue.